# Rails mistakenly saying to add postgres to bundle

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a rails project that uses mysql (and has so successfully in the past). However, after upgrading my postgres installation, this rails project is throwing the adapter not installed error:

```
/Users/stuartnelson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:214:in `block in replace_gem': Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (LoadError)
```

My `database.yml` file correctly declares the adapter as `mysql2`.

I tried installing the activerecord-postgresql-adapter gem as recommended (but didn't add it to my gemfile, because I'm not using postgres), but that did not fix the problem.

I am still able to log in to the mysql server on my machine and verify that the database and its tables exist.

The stacktrace does show that rails is trying to use the postgres adapter, but no where in the project do I indicate to use postgres.

```
from /Users/stuartnelson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mfacs/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/stuartnelson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mfacs/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/stuartnelson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mfacs/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/stuartnelson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mfacs/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/stuartnelson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mfacs/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
```

Somehow, monkeying with my postgres install caused this (I think). Does anyone have any experience with this and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you please include your Gemfile.

Comment: Looks like you have `pg` instead of `mysql2` in your Gemfile.

Comment: Aside: When it says add it to the Gemfile, it's not kidding; Bundler doesn't expose anything not in the Gemfile (that's the whole point), so no, simply *installing* a gem won't ever fix a dependency error.

Comment: My gemfile does not include `pg`. It has `mysql2`. It is also bundled with `mysql2`, `pg` does not appear in the Gemfile.lock.

Comment: what's the output of `bundle install` ?

Comment: bundle install is successful, no errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. For a different project, I was exporting an environment variable DATABASE_URL for use with a golang blog that I have deployed to heroku. Heroku uses DATABASE_URL, so I figured I could just set that on my local machine so I wouldn't have to toggle between dev and prod db urls.

As it turns out, if you have DATABASE_URL exported, rails IGNORES any database.yml information in favor of this. Hence, rails was trying to use the postgres address I had declared. This is how heroku makes it easy to hook up your rails app to their postgres db.

Removing this environment variable on my local machine solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will occur when you have `postgresql` as an adapter for a database configuration in your app's `config/database.yml` and you do not have the `pg` gem installed.

Comment: As stated in my question, my database.yml file declares mysql2 as the adapter, not postgresql